# Magento admin users not added by me

Tags: magento2, admin, access

I opened the users page from the link https://mywebsite/admin/admin/user/ , I found the admin user that I used to access with, and I found another two users that I have never added before, are these added while I installed the theme?,  and their roles are admin.
could you explain this for me? is this safe? shall I worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a super admin you can set fixed permissions for these accounts. Or if it's not created by you, you can remove it from your site.